# Update a string value in loop

Tags: string, for-loop, go

Is it possible to update the value of a string when we execute a for loop?

```
package main 
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func Chop(r int, s string) string {
    return s[r:]
}

func main() {
    s:= "ThisIsAstring1ThisIsAstring2ThisIsAstring3"
    for strings.Contains(s, "string") {
        // Original value > ThisIsAstring1ThisIsAstring2ThisIsAstring3
        fmt.Println(s)
        // I delete a part of the string > ThisIsAstring1
        remove := len(s)/3
        // Now, I update the value of string > string := ThisIsAstring2ThisIsAstring3
        s := Chop(remove, s)
        fmt.Println(s)
        break
    }
}
```

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You have several issues; using a reserved keyword as a variable, sending a float as an int param.. did you even try to compile this?

Comment: I guarantee the code you posted as-is will not work, regardless of the presence of a break. I think the main thing you're missing is that you have a new variable "string", instead of assigning the old value (before the loop). Take of the := on the string assignment, and use just =.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no clue what the use case is, but here goes. Let's start with identifying the issues in your code:

```
// You cannot use a reserved keyword "string" as a variable name
string:= "ThisIsAstring1ThisIsAstring2ThisIsAstring3"
for strings.Contains(string, "string") {
    // Remove is a float, but you need to pass an int into your chop function
    remove := len(string)/3
    // You're reassigning your string variable. You really just want =, not :=
    string := Chop(remove, string)
    fmt.Println(string)
}
```

Now, here's a solution that will work for your use case:

```
str := "ThisIsAstring1ThisIsAstring2ThisIsAstring3"
for strings.Contains(str, "string") {
    fmt.Println(str)
    remove := int(len(str) / 3)
    str = Chop(remove, str)
}
fmt.Println(str)
```

GoPlay:
https://play.golang.org/p/NdROIFDS_5

Comment: I did the changes after your answer. Now, it works! Thank you so much @william.taylor.09